# Bool и rand() c++

Tags: c++

Что означает это выражение?

```
bool Variable = rand() % 2 == 0;
```

`bool Variable = rand() % 2` с этим все понятно, если `0` - `false`, `1` - `true`, но вот что происходит дальше?

Comment: Приоритеты операций... У присваиваний минимальный.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`==` - знак эквивалентности. Т.е. в Вашем случае, `rand() % 2 == 0`. Если левая сторона равна `0`, то она эквивалентна правой, поэтому в `Variable` помещается `true`. Если левая часть равна `1`, то эквивалентности нет, поэтому `Variable == false`

Answer (score 1):

Это же проверка четности/нечетности случ. числа.

`Variable = 1`, если оно четно, и `0`, если нечетно.

Comment: За что минус влепили? Код выше действительно генерирует "случайный" бит чётности. Было ли так задуманно? Мы не знаем. Но минусовать тут нечего.

Comment: @ixSci автора вопроса вряд ли поймет этот ответ; вряд ли это именно проверка четности.

Comment: @Etki, подобные минусы стоит пояснять, чтобы автор ответа исправил/поспорил. Есть неадекватные ответы или попросту неправильные - так да, стоит минусовать без зазрения совести, но тут другой случай. Ответ ничем не хуже других, поэтому минусовать *молча* его не стоит.